# How should I cancel the execution of a cell in jupyer notebook <ith vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I run a cell and then I want to stop the execution, I don't know how to do it : on google collab, there is a little stop button on which we have to click to stop the cell (it raises a Keyboard Interrupt).
On Vscode I found this red square but only if I click on "run by line" on the top of the cell, which is not what I want to do...
The only way I found to do it is the kill the whole kernel which is not a good idea either

Is there a way to stop the execution of a cell ?